# Storing and comparing multiple passwords with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, authentication, passwords, servicestack, password-hash

I'm attempting to create a password expiration function in my application. Passwords are already set up as well as authentication and changing passwords. Now I want to prompt the user to change their password after x amount of time.

When the user goes to change their password and my Angular frontend makes that request I want my C# Service Stack API to compare the given new password with the current password and the password before that to check for duplication.

I'm not worried about slight variations. If the user submits the same password but with one extra character for example, that's fine. I want to be an simple as possible to start.

The passwords are stored in a MS SQL Server in two columns `Salt varchar(8000)` and `PasswordHash varchar(8000)`. I've got everything set up I'm just very confused on how to compare the hashed password with the string provided by the User. Then save the old password in a new hashed column. I've been searching the web and SOF for three days now and I haven't found anything. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a new row, not a new column. You'd compare them just like you'd verify them: Hash the user entry according to your algorithm and compare hashes. If they are different, the password was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on @Fildor comment, you'll need to create an audit history of password changes containing the hashes of existing passwords. From [ServiceStack v5+](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.0.0#pbkdf2-password-hashing-implementation) ServiceStack switched to use the same PBKDF2 password hashing algorithm ASP.NET Identity v3 uses which stores the password hash + salt + iterations + algorithm version in a single **PasswordHash** field on `UserAuth` table, so your password audit history table only needs a single column to store the existing password hash.

The password hashing algorithm is available from the [IPasswordHasher](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Auth/IPasswordHasher.cs) dependency, which you can use in your Service implementation like:

```
public IPasswordHasher PasswordHasher { get; set; }

public object Any(AllowPassword request)
{
    var passwordHashes = MyRepo.GetExistingUserPasswords(GetSession().UserAuthId);
    foreach (var passwordHash in passwordHashes)
    {
        if (PasswordHasher.VerifyPassword(passwordHash, request.Password, out var neeedsRehash)
            throw new ArgumentException("Can't use existing password", nameof(request.Password));
    }

    return new AllowPasswordResponse();
}
```

Comment: Okay, awesome. Before your answer I was attempting to use `SaltedHash.GetHashAndSaltString()`. But your solution looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: @marcusshep `IHashProvider.GetHashAndSaltString()` was the old hashing algorithm which stored passwordHash, salt in 2 fields. All passwords since v5 are hashed with the newer `IPasswordHasher` algorithm.

Comment: We're on ServiceStack v4, unfortunately. Like I mentioned in the question, the salt and hash are being stored in two separate fields. So, my Password History table is going to have to have UserId, Hash, Salt. @mythz